# Problems with new 2sxc faq app

Tags: 2sxc

Anyone had any luck with this?

I'm using 9.04.01 on DNN 9.

There doesn't appear to be a way to add a question unlike it's previous version.
The previous version had a `+` sign in the menu on the right to add a new question. This version doesn't. Is there a different way to add questions in this version?

[Images http://robertveale.com/](http://robertveale.com/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually ran into something different. Please check http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/12-differences-when-templating-data-instead-of-content to understand this

Your first view shows a list of content-assigned-to-the-module so you have the inline +.

The second view shows a list querying the DB, so hitting + wouldn't add it below that but anywhere else, so it's not part of the item-toolbar. If you need a + on the query-view, then the most common solution is to provide a separate + button - see for example how the blog-app does it here: https://github.com/2sic/app-blog/blob/master/_1%20Main%20blog%20view.cshtml#L24-L38

```
@* toolbar for add / manage posts *@
@Edit.Toolbar(toolbar: new object[] { 
    new { 
        command = new { 
            action = "new", 
            contentType = "BlogPost"
        } 
    },
    new { 
        command = new { 
            action = "contentitems", 
            contentType = "BlogPost"
        },
        showCondition = true
    }
}, settings: new { hover="left", show = "hover" })
```

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you've put in to help me out.
But I still don't see how to add a question.
I understand that some of the menu functions would be moot in some cases, i.e. sorting when there's only one item. I understand the differences between the content and data paradigms.

On the page of the link you supplied, 'Item 10 In-Page Toolbars' shows what I cannot find. The "Content-Paradigm" bubble you have, has the arrow pointing to the menu item where the "+" is that is missing. And the "Content-Only Buttons" bubble points to a menu that does not exist in the FAQ module.

Comment: Both of those menus though are visible and available in the Accordion app and I presume that these apps are built similarly. I can manipulate the Accordion module easily but the same menu options are just not available in the latest version of the FAQ app. Again the previous version does have these menus available.

Unfortunately, I can't install the older version as the install processes forces the upgrade.

Also in 'Item 9 Removing Content...' the arrow again points to a menu that is not available in the FAQ app.

Comment: I rechecked and the buttons appear correctly. On the view which shows "own" items the + is there, on those which show a queried extract of all data it isn't there - as is the defined behaviour.